# Why is there the need for browser resets?

Tags: css, reset, stylesheet

Okay that's probably not the best title, I know *why* we need browser resets: because browsers have different defaults set.

My question that was too long to put into a title is:

If everyone needs to use a reset stylesheet 90% of the time, why do browsers need to set default styles?  We're just going to remove them anyways, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because certain rules make sense by default:

- Table cells have `display:table-cell;`
- `<b>` makes text bold, `<i>` makes text italic
- Paragraphs should have space in between them
- Unordered lists should be displayed as bulleted lists

The problem isn't that browsers have defaults, it's that the defaults are all different.

Comment: Via @BalusC 's link on his linked answer: http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head - to do something reasonable when displaying plain html, not styled sites.

Answer (score 1):

Because not *everyone* uses a "reset stylesheet". The biggest example off the top of my head is Wikipedia, which displays content in the browser's default font.

Comment: That's not quite true.  It uses sans-serif.

Answer (score 1):

The reset stylesheets are in my humble opinion only useful for starters who are ranting on the minor styling differences among browsers and doesn't know the default behaviours/styles from top of head so that they're **forced** to fill all of those styles in the CSS themselves.

If you want to see more thoughts behind this opinionated answer, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886657/are-margin-and-padding-most-disbalanced-thing-among-all-browser/2886817#2886817).

Answer (score 0):

It is because it gets you into a known state and therefore will look similar across a variety of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

basically, it's a way to keep results as universal as possible by defeating any browser-based rules and omissions before your CSS is applied. http://www.css-reset.com/

See presentation on this page http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-reset/