# What's the standard margin of a <p> element?

Tags: html, css

We're using a Html Wrapper supplied by a client, which references a reset style sheet that sets the `<p>` element's margin to 0px. I'd like to have a normal top & bottom margin with my `<p>` elements, so can somebody tell me what it should be?

Comment: You might want to check [this question on the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819161/what-is-the-default-padding-and-or-margin-for-a-p-element-reset-css).

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browser specific CSS defaults are outlined [here](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm).

Here's an extract of relevance for the margin of the `p` element:

- W3: `1.12em 0`
- IE7: `14.25pt 0`
- IE8: `1em 0`
- FF2: `1em 0`
- FF3: `1em 0`
- Opera: `1em 0`
- Safari 3.1: `1em 0`

Reset stylesheets are by the way ridiculous. Just set the desired margin *yourself* if you want it to be consistent among browsers.

```
p {
    margin: .75em 0;
}
```

#### See also:

- [Are padding and margin most disbalanced among browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886657/are-margin-and-padding-most-disbalanced-thing-among-all-browser/2886817#2886817)

Comment: +1 for the detail, but disagree with you on reset stylesheets. I find they save me time as I don't need to troubleshoot nearly as many browser inconsistencies. However, this benefit disappears if the site has need to optimize for high volume traffic.

Comment: FYI- your first [link](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm) is dead with an Internal Server Error.

Comment: @Sparky: Bug in their server code. If they don't fix it soon enough, check the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7KiUoJ9JPLoJ:css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com).

Answer (score 6):

They're browser dependent.  That's why most people use a reset sheet - to normalize them before they attempt to customize them.

Comment: Is there a margin that *most* browsers use?

Comment: No, there is no set requirement or 'standard'.  My advice would be to keep the reset sheet, and then set your top and bottom to what you want to see.

Comment: “No, there is no set requirement or 'standard'” — that’s not exactly what was asked though. I think most browsers use 1em. Like most use 16px as a default font size, and 1.2 as a default line height.

Comment: http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm has a (non-exhaustive) list of default styles applied by a variety of browsers. But yes, personally I'd simply reset these to my own values, not try to second-guess the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The default margin is `1em`, as suggested in [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/html/#margins-and-padding).